# No input file specified - Homestead, vagrant

Tags: nginx, vagrant

> No input file specified.

is the error message displayed in the browser.

I hear you saying: "No input file specified" means you need to check the folder mappings in the `Homestead.yaml` file, well

`C:\Users\Andy\Homestead\Homestead.yaml`

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/Homestead/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
 - ~/Homestead/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
 - map: ~/Code
   to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
 - map: test.local
   to: ~/Code/test.local

databases:
 - homestead
```

My `Homestead.yaml` file is formatted correctly i.e. no tabs only spaces and directories are mapped correctly.

My project is a simple one to begin with:

`C:\Users\Andy\Code\test.local\index.php`

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

On the VM:

```
vagrant@homestead:~$ ls -l /home/vagrant/Code/
drwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant 0 Apr 14 09:37 test.local
```

So clearly, it exists

My hosts file is in place and mapped to the correct IP

```
192.168.10.10       test.local
```

The VM boots successfully:

```
$ vagrant reload --provision
...
 homestead-7: SSH username: vagrant
 homestead-7: SSH auth method: private key
 ==> homestead-7: Machine booted and ready!
 ==> homestead-7: Checking for guest additions in VM...
 ==> homestead-7: Setting hostname...
...
 homestead-7: Running: script: Creating Certificate: test.local
 ==> homestead-7: Running provisioner: shell...
 homestead-7: Running: script: Creating Site: test.local
 ==> homestead-7: Running provisioner: shell...
 homestead-7: Running: script: Restarting Nginx
...
```

I've tried

```
$ vagrant reload --provision
```

What can it be then? No matter what, I receive

No input file specified.

Edit:
Adding

```
rewrite ^/index\.php/(.*)$ /$1 permanent;
location / {
 index index.php;
```

to `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/test.local` and restarting the nginx server I now receive a 404 Not Found in the browser, I guess this is progress?

Looking at the error log:

```
2017/04/17 12:15:00 [error] 3538#3538: *1 "/usr/share/nginx/~/Code/test.local/index.php" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 192.168.10.1, server: test.local, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "test.local"
```

Clearly the path above looks faulty. <strike>How is my `Homestead.yaml` file connected to `/usr/share/nginx/...` that is, how do i define the correct path?</strike>

We got there in the end. With:

```
sites:
 - map: test.local
   to: /home/vagrant/Code/test.local
```

and `vagrant reload --provision` we hit the `index.php` file successfully.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. What are you trying and what is your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One should check the Nginx' access.log and the `C:\Users\Andy\Code\test.local\index.php` does not contain a reference to the homestead.yaml.

[This Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25268662/2777965) explains how to solve the issue. Be sure that the Nginx config contains a reference to the php file:

> ```
> rewrite ^/index\.php/(.*)$ /$1 permanent;
> location / {
>     index index.php;
>     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$args;
> }
> ```